# Is there such a thing as Waifu-Wednesday?

Tags: culture

I found an interesting phrase here on [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=221993554672297&set=a.153417188196601.1073741828.153144811557172&type=1&relevant_count=1),

[image]

What is Waifu-Wednesday? Is there such a thing as Waifu-Wednesday?

Comment: it's Facebook, do you really believe that?

Comment: @Memor-X That's why I ask it here :)

Comment: well this isn't an answer and just me but it's Facebook, i don't normally take what's posted there with even a grain of salt, anyone can make a page for anything

Comment: It's a common-ish internet trend among the self-proclaimed otaku of the world where they post images of girls (often dozens) they consider their [*waifu*](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4754/274). There is such a thing, but simply because it's common as aforementioned; there is no "official" thing about it. Perhaps someone can provide a more fulfilling answer.

Comment: @eric Well, thats all there pretty much is to it. Not much else to say about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. No Waifu wednesday is not a officially recognized day for waifu's. Yes, it is a commonly used term in the Waifu-owning society.

Right now, Waifu Wednesday is used by people that have a Waifu/Husbando and use Waifu Wednesday as a mid week appreciation point for their Waifu. This is mostly done by spreading the love of their waifu's by posting Moe and or Kawaii pictures of their Waifu/Husbando.

For those not familiar with the term Waifu Check out ["where does the term "waifu" come from?"](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/where-does-the-term-waifu-come-from)

Comment: you could also use this link to add more information about the term "waifu" http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/where-does-the-term-waifu-come-from

Comment: @Memor-X Nice, did not know/remember that was there :).